Set SELinux labels in Docker build
I'm trying to produce a squashfs image with labeled files for SELinux. I'm building this using docker buildx. Both of the ideas I tried failed:

setfattr and chcon do not work on SELinux-enforcing hosts for labeling files inside the container filesystem. Just returns invalid argument. If I manage to get this working I can set labels on
When using mksquashfs with its options to set xattrs I can only set a single label for a batch of files. However, when I first added /etc with say /etc/a and then try to append /etc/b, mksquashfs will create /etc_1 in the squashfs, ruining everything

fakeroot might help, but it's not trivial to get into the build environment and I'm unsure whether or not it'll work at all.

Fakeroot indeed works for this (note: all operations like chcon to alter the labels should be ran in the same script as mksquashfs, and the script itself is ran as fakeroot /se-squashfs.sh /rootfs
